# Electron webview loadURL POST

Tags: node.js, electron

I couldn't find any similar question on SO.

Could someone show me an example on how to use loadURL with POST?  I'm currently doing the following

```
const url = firebaseCloudFunctionURL+"/endpointAPI";
const webview = document.createElement('webview');
webview.setAttribute("src", "https://www.nytimes.com/"); // forces dom-ready event to be called
webview.addEventListener('dom-ready', () => {
    const postDict = {
        query: "test_string"
    };            
    webview.loadURL(url, {postData: postDict});
});
```

But the web server shows that the request body is empty.
(Using Firebase cloud functions)

```
exports.endpointAPI = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
    const test = req.body.shop;
    console.log("req.body "+ JSON.stringify(req.body));
});
```

Which yields "req.body {}" in logs.

In the [electron documentation](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/webview-tag#webviewloadurlurl-options) postData is written with UploadRawData[].  But there is no example code.  Has anyone ever gotten it to work?

Comment: You got it working ?

Answer (score 1):

Per documentation suggest, you should supply postData to conform type of 
`Array<UploadRawData> | Array<UploadFile> | Array<UploadFileSystem> | Array<UploadBlob>`, so it is expected to not being sent as you just appended plain object instead. For simpliest pseudo example like below

```
webview.loadURL(url, {
    postData: [{
      type: 'rawData',
      bytes: Buffer.from('test_string2')
    }]
  })
```

shows post with buffer object for given strings. First, you should send array, secondly you should follow correct type for accepted object types.

Comment: OJ Kwon Didn't work, req.body is still coming as empty.

Comment: I have confirmed via https://requestb.in/ post body comes in correctly with given snippet. Try to check with any server you can actually see raw response, I'm pretty sure if it doesn't work either client code has something missing or server configures something incorrect.

Comment: I am trying it like : ```
webview.loadURL(`http://localhost:3000/posturl`, {
      postData: [{
        type: 'rawData',
        bytes: Buffer.from('token=token&redirectTo=redirect_url')
      }]
    });
```

Comment: On server request params and body both are coming empty.

Comment: @MuhammadYawarAli no I'm seeing the same thing you see, the request body is empty on the server

Comment: [any idea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59816741/capture-webview-requests-and-responses) how to capture the requests/responses of a `webview`?

Answer (score 1):

Be sure to set `extraHeaders`:

```js
webview.loadURL(url, {
  postData: [{
    type: "rawData",
    bytes: Buffer.from("foo=bar")
  }],
  extraHeaders: "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8"
});
```

Comment: [any idea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59816741/capture-webview-requests-and-responses) how to capture the requests/responses of a `webview`?