# Capture webview requests and responses

Tags: javascript, node.js, webview, electron, httpresponse

I am creating an app in which the user can browse the web via a `webview` element.

```
<webview src='user-generated'></webview>
```

I would like to be able to capture all of the requests and responses that are generated in the process. I have been looking around for the past two hours trying to figure out how to do this, but have not found anything even remotely relevant.

I read something about using `session` to retrieve session cookies, and I had imagined other stuff like requests and responses, although it does not seem to return anything useful to this end.

```
webview.addEventListener('dom-ready', function(){
  console.log(remote.getCurrentWindow().webContents.session)
})
```

**Is there any way to capture all of the requests and responses, ideally with `webview`?**

---

Here is what I got so far, and, although it is returning what seems to be requests or responses, I am not yet sure if it is from webview. I will have to take a closer look tomorrow.

## main

```
ipcMain.on('asynchronous-message', (event, arg) => {
  session.defaultSession.webRequest.onBeforeSendHeaders((details, callback) => {
    event.reply('asynchronous-reply', details)
    callback({ requestHeaders: details.requestHeaders })
  })
})
```

## renderer

```
ipcRenderer.send('asynchronous-message', webview) // Should I be sending `webview` as the argument?
ipcRenderer.on('asynchronous-reply', (event, payload) => {
  console.log(paylod)
})
```

Comment: can you check this out? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50974767/electron-manipulate-intercept-webview-requests-and-responses

Comment: @AritraChakraborty i came across that post 4 hours ago already. i dont see how it lets me do what i wanna do? thanks anyways tho

Answer (score 0):

You can access the onBeforeSendHeaders on the webview session. Easiest way to get the session is by setting the webview partition.

```
<webview src='user-generated' partition='my-webview-partition'></webview>
```

**main**

```
var ses = session.fromPartition('my-webview-partition');
ses.webRequest.onBeforeRequestHeaders((details, callback) => {
  details.requestHeaders['User-Agent'] = 'MyAgent'
  callback({ requestHeaders: details.requestHeaders })
});
```